# Use button to filter through an array map in React?

Tags: reactjs, arrays, react-hooks, mapping, state

I'm working on a portfolio site and I want to have 2 buttons, 1 for "print" and 1 for "digital".

In react I have all my projects set up in a array of objects file called "ProjectsList".

How can I make it so when I click on a button, it filters the items in my array map and only displays the ones with the same 'category' value?

At the moment I can only get it so when I click the buttons it returns them all as "true" but can't get it to change the actual state of an object item to false if it doesn't match the button's id that I clicked.

index.jsx file:

```
import React, { useState } from "react"
import Seo from "../../components/seo"
import ProjectItem from "./ProjectItem";


export default function ProjectsPage() {

    const [active, setActive] = useState();


    return (
        <>
            <Seo title="Home" />
            <div className="container">
               <ProjectItem />
            </div>
        </>
    )
}
```

ProjectItem.jsx file:

```
import React, { useState } from "react"
import { Link } from "gatsby"
import { ProjectsList } from "./data";

export default function ProjectItem() {

    const [active, setActive] = useState();

    function getCategories(e) {

        {ProjectsList.map((item, i) => {
                if (e.target.id == item.category) {
                    setActive(true)
                }
                else {
                    setActive(false)
                }
            })
        }

    }

    return (
        <>
            <h2>Projects</h2>
            <div className="double-buttons spacer-4">
                <button className="button" id="print" onClick={(e) => getCategories(e)}>
                    Print Button
                </button>
                <button className="button" id="digital" onClick={(e) => getCategories(e)}>
                    Digital Button
                </button>
            </div>

            <div className="grid--col-4" id="projectsSection">

                {
                    ProjectsList.map((item, i) => {
                        return (
                            <Link
                                to={item.path}
                                className={active ? 'project-tile active' : 'project-tile hidden'}
                                key={i}>
                                <div className="grid__cell">
                                    <img src={item.backgroundUrl} alt={item.title} />
                                    <div className="grid__cell__title">
                                        <h4>{item.title}</h4>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </Link>
                        )
                    }
                    )
                }

            </div>
        </>
    )

}
```

data.js array file:

```
export const ProjectsList = [
    {
        title: 'Project 1',
        backgroundUrl: 'backgroundUrl',
        path: '#',
        category: 'print',
        active: true
    },
    {
        title: 'Project 2',
        backgroundUrl: 'backgroundUrl',
        path: '#',
        category: 'digital',
        active: true
    },
    {
        title: 'Project 3',
        backgroundUrl: 'backgroundUrl',
        path: '#',
        category: 'print',
        active: true
    },
    {
        title: 'Project 4',
        backgroundUrl: 'backgroundUrl',
        path: '#',
        category: 'digital',
        active: true
    },
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a state for the projectList so that when you change any of the data it's saved and then rendered with the new value. In your case each time It re-renders it returns the original data from the file. So I just to make something like this.

```
const [projectList, setProjectList] = useState([
    {
        title: 'Project 1',
        backgroundUrl: 'backgroundUrl',
        path: '#',
        category: 'print',
        active: true
    },
    {
        title: 'Project 2',
        backgroundUrl: 'backgroundUrl',
        path: '#',
        category: 'digital',
        active: true
    },
    {
        title: 'Project 3',
        backgroundUrl: 'backgroundUrl',
        path: '#',
        category: 'print',
        active: true
    },
    {
        title: 'Project 4',
        backgroundUrl: 'backgroundUrl',
        path: '#',
        category: 'digital',
        active: true
    },
])
```

So when you click digital or print button the onClick function will be something like this

```
const getCategories = useCallback(()=>{
    const newProjectList = [...projectList]
    newProjectsList.map((item, i) => {
                if (e.target.id == item.category) {
                    item.active = true
                }
                else {
                    item.active = false
                }
            })
    setProjectList(newProjectList)
},[projectList, setProjectList])
```

I replaced the active state because it is useless as it is not connected to each project. So I changed each project status in the main object from true to false based on which button is clicked.

You need also to modify this to read the state of each project.

```
{
    ProjectsList.map((item, i) => {
        return (
            <Link
                to={item.path}
                className={item.active ? 'project-tile active' : 'project-tile hidden'}
                key={i}>
                <div className="grid__cell">
                    <img src={item.backgroundUrl} alt={item.title} />
                    <div className="grid__cell__title">
                        <h4>{item.title}</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </Link>
        )
    }
    )
}
```

Comment: Thanks that's very helpful! When you say "modify this to read the state of each project" do you mean add conditional formatting E.G. "{projectList && }"?

Getting a few errors so just working my way through them.

Comment: No I meant to replace `active` with `item.active` each project active state